# No way to get scope for current http request (Autofac 4)?

Tags: asp.net-core, autofac, asp.net-core-mvc

How can we get **ILifetimeScope** for current http request when HttpContext exists? E.g. I want to resolve service from static extension method. I don't want to create new instance of scope by BeginLifetimeScope() method.

I spend few hours and didn't found solution..

Comment: Are you just asking to access the scoped IServiceProvider? That one is provided on `HttpContext.RequestServices` and can be get via `context.RequestServices.GetService<IMyService>()`. The `IServiceProvider` is the base container interface for ASP.NET Core DI (`IServiceCollection` is the counterpart for building/configuring the IoC container)

Comment: Anyways, using Singleton pattern is a bad idea. Better to refactor your code and you should refactor your code to work with DI/IoC

Answer (score 23, accepted):

*Note: this was originally cross-posted as an [issue/question on Autofac](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/760) where there is more context.*

Based on the code posted in the Autofac issue, you basically have a reference to the application container, you can resolve an `IHttpContextAccessor`, and from there you can get the current `HttpContext`. From there you want to resolve request-level services and are stuck.

First, it's important to note that **a key difference in ASP.NET Core is that it handles the request scope creation, not Autofac.** In fact, ASP.NET Core handles pretty much everything as far as initiating resolution of services and so forth. Autofac backs the DI container interfaces, but the engine driving the calls to Autofac - including the creation and storage of the request scope - is all ASP.NET Core. (You can see [in the ASP.NET "Hosting" repo where this happens.](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/Internal/RequestServicesFeature.cs)).

Knowing that, it can help troubleshoot issues like this - you'll know not to look in Autofac code and instead chase down things in ASP.NET Core.

What you'll notice is that **on the ASP.NET Core `HttpContext` [there is a property `RequestServices`](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions/HttpContext.cs#L61). That property is the request lifetime scope for ASP.NET Core.** So if you need to do a simple resolve of a service from an `HttpContext`, you can use that:

```
var accessor = _container.Resolve<IHttpContextAccessor>();
var context = accessor.HttpContext;
var resolved = context.RequestServices.GetService<MyService>();
```

If you absolutely must have an Autofac-specific request lifetime scope, you can resolve an `ILifetimeScope` from the request services. You can always resolve the current lifetime scope from a scope/container, so the scope you get will be the request scope.

```
var accessor = _container.Resolve<IHttpContextAccessor>();
var context = accessor.HttpContext;
var scope = context.RequestServices.GetService<ILifetimeScope>();
var resolved = scope.Resolve<MyService>();
```

Comment: Thank you Travis! You saved my life :) P.s.: fix asp.net hosting repository link

Comment: Link fixed. Glad I could help.

Comment: @TravisIllig is there a way to get an Autofac-specific request lifetime scope (e.g. from an HttpContext) in traditional ASP.NET?

Comment: [Covered in the docs.](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/webforms.html#id3) Classic ASP.NET requires you have a container accessor; the web request lifetime is ambient and attached to that.