# UseServiceProviderFactory doesn't affect HttpContext.RequestServices

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I am trying to override service provider factory by using `UseServiceProviderFactory` method. The problem is, while it seems to affect `app.Services`, it does not affect `HttpContext.RequestServices`, and also does not work with Controller. Here is my code for proof-of-concept:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text.Json;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Host.UseServiceProviderFactory(new MyFactory());
var app = builder.Build();

// works fine here
var i = app.Services.GetService<MyInstance>();
Debug.Assert(i != null);
Console.WriteLine(i.X);

app.MapGet("/", async c =>
{
    // i is always null here
    var i = c.RequestServices.GetService<MyInstance>();
    await c.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(i);
});

app.Run();

// classes 

class ContainerBuilder
{
    public ContainerBuilder(IServiceCollection serviceDescriptors)
    {
        ServiceDescriptors = serviceDescriptors;
    }

    public IServiceCollection ServiceDescriptors { get; }
}

class MyInstance { public int X => 42; }

class MyServiceScopeFactory : IServiceScopeFactory
{
    public IServiceScope CreateScope()
    {
        // never got called
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

class MyServiceProvider : IServiceProvider
{
    private readonly ServiceProvider _services;

    public MyServiceProvider(ServiceProvider services) => _services = services;

    public object? GetService(Type serviceType)
    {        
        if (serviceType == typeof(MyInstance)) 
            return new MyInstance();
        else if (serviceType == typeof(IServiceScopeFactory)) 
            // this line never got hit
            return new MyServiceScopeFactory();
        else return _services.GetService(serviceType);
    }
}

class MyFactory : IServiceProviderFactory<ContainerBuilder>
{
    public ContainerBuilder CreateBuilder(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        return new ContainerBuilder(services);
    }

    public IServiceProvider CreateServiceProvider(ContainerBuilder containerBuilder)
    {
        return new MyServiceProvider(containerBuilder.ServiceDescriptors.BuildServiceProvider());
    }
}
```

I have checked and compared with AutoFac's implementation but I cannot see what I am missing.

Comment: For the official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext.requestservices?view=aspnetcore-6.0),it looks like HttpContext.RequestServices gets or sets the IServiceProvider that provides access to the request's service container.And `UseServiceProviderFactory` overrides the factory used to create the service provider.I think maybe you need  to check the source code of `UseServiceProviderFactory` and `HttpContext.RequestServices`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37891598/no-way-to-get-scope-for-current-http-request-autofac-4 seems similar to this thread

Comment: @Maksym Thank you but I think it is different issue. After some investigation I found out that it is actually my design flaw but still have no time to write an explanation yet.